# Math competition function with parameter problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, proof-verification, parametric

Given a function $$f(x) = \frac{ax + 2}{3x - \frac{1}{a}}$$ find every possible value of the parameter $a$ such that for all real values $x$ for which $f(x)$ is defined it is true that $f(f(x))$ is also defined and $f(f(x))=x$

After manipulating the equation $$\frac{a\left(\frac{ax+2}{3x-\frac{1}{a}}\right)+2}{3\left(\frac{ax+2}{3x-\frac{1}{a}}\right)-\frac{1}{a}}$$ I got $$x\left(\left(a-\frac{1}{a}\right)x + \frac{1}{a^2} - a^2\right) = 0$$. This expression is zero if $x$ is zero or $\left(a-\frac{1}{a}\right)x + \frac{1}{a^2} - a^2$ is zero. Since the second expression must be zero for all $x$, $$a - \frac{1}{a}=0$$ and $$-a^2 + \frac{1}{a^2}=0$$.
Adding these two equations we get $$a^4 - a^3 - a + 1 = 0$$
Factoring this we get $$(a-1)(a+1)(a^2-a+1)=0$$
so $a$ can be 1 or -1 since $a^2-a+1$ doesn't have any real solutions.

Comment: Maybe show some work, like (in terms of $a$) compute the formula $f(f(x)=x=0.$

Comment: Above meant formula $f(f(x))-x=0.$ [too late to edit comment.]

Comment: A lazy argument, but that requires some knowledge about those types of functions could be: $f$ is defined at $x=-2/a$ and $f(-2/a)=0$. While $f(0)=-2a$. Therefore, you need $-2/a=-2a$. In other words $a^2=1$. Since $f(x)=x$ has two fixed points, the condition $a^2=1$ is enough.

Comment: As a function of $x,$ you have a Moebius transformation. These behave very well, which is why this is not a difficult calculation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation  For example, it is enough to use the two by two coefficient matrix, you are allowed to multiply all entries by $a,$ and are just asking when the matrix squared is a scalar multiple of the identity matrix

Comment: @WillJagy I'm sure that this is a nice way to solve the problem, but it was expected of me to solve it using simple methods, without advanced mathematics. I'm really looking for these kinds of solutions

Comment: if your last line in your edit is correct, you only get $0$ for every real $x$ if $a = \frac{1}{a}$

Answer (score 1):

From $$x\left(\left(a-\frac{1}{a}\right)x + \frac{1}{a^2} - a^2\right) = 0$$
you can ignore the possibility $x=0$ because this is supposed to work for all $x$, so we need $$\left(a-\frac{1}{a}\right)x + \frac{1}{a^2} - a^2 = 0$$
Now note that $\frac 1{a^2}-a^2-=(a-\frac1a)(a+\frac 1a) $ so our equation becomes either $$a-\frac 1a=0\\a=\pm 1$$
or $$x-a+\frac 1a=0$$
but this depends on $x$, so is not true for all values of $x$.  Our solution is $$a=\pm 1$$